# How to pass parameters in wordpress shortcode?

Tags: php, shortcode, comments, parameter

Everything is working fine and it's displaying the comments of the current page with this shortcode [wpdiscuz_comments] using the code below.

```
function my_wpdiscuz_shortcode() {
$html = "";
if (file_exists(ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/themes/default/comment-form.php")) {
ob_start();
include_once ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/themes/default/comment-form.php";
$html = ob_get_clean();
}
return $html;
}
add_shortcode("wpdiscuz_comments", "my_wpdiscuz_shortcode");
```

I'm trying to pass id parameter using the shortcode below. But it's not working.

```
[wpdiscuz_comments post_id="22"]
```

Where "post_id" parameter fetching the comments of only post id 22. So I can fetch the comments of a specific post.

Can anyone please help me with this or let me know how can I pass the parameters with shortcode using the above code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the docs for [add_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/) state,

> Every shortcode callback is passed three parameters by default, including an array of attributes ($atts), the shortcode content or null if not set ($content), and finally the shortcode tag itself ($shortcode_tag), in that order.

Use the [`shortcode_atts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/shortcode_atts/) to define what attributes are allowed and set default values for those attributes.

```
function my_wpdiscuz_shortcode( $_atts ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'post_id' => '',
    );
    $atts = shortcode_atts( $defaults, $_atts );
    // Confirm that $post_id is an integer.
    $atts['post_id'] = absint( $atts['post_id'] );
    // ----
    // Now you can use $atts['post_id'] - it will contain
    // the integer value of the post_id set in the shortcode, or
    // 0 if nothing is set in the shortcode.
    // ----
    $html = "";
    if (file_exists(ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/themes/default/comment-form.php")) {
        ob_start();
        include_once ABSPATH . "wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/themes/default/comment-form.php";
        $html = ob_get_clean();
    }
    return $html;
}
add_shortcode("wpdiscuz_comments", "my_wpdiscuz_shortcode");
```

Note that, if `post_id` isn't set in your shortcode call, it will default to `0`.

Comment: Hi Pat, Thank you so much for your quick reply. I've tried it with the above code but still it's not working. [wpdiscuz_comments post_id="1"]

Comment: It's still showing the current post comments instead of the post id I'm inserting.

Comment: My code doesn't make use of the `$atts['post_id']` anywhere. You'd have to pass that value to whatever you're using to display the comments. Currently it appears you're loading the theme's `comments-form.php` file; you might want to look at using something like [`get_comments( array( 'post_id' => $atts['post_id'] ) )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) instead.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm currently using the plugin to display form & comments called Wpdiscuz. And I'm adding this code in the functions.php file.